# What is a fire that is not a wildfire?

Tags: antonyms, phrase-requests

Do we have "civil(-ized) fire"?

*Wildfire* is a forest fire, an uncontrolled fire, and metaphorically, anything that is uncontrolled and destructive.

Fire also occurs other than in the wild, may be uncontrolled or uncontrollable on occasions, is almost always destructive.

**Q:** What is a fire that is not a *wildfire*, i.e., one that is not in a forest but in a developed zone?

*meta*: Incongruous how many sources say the antonym of *wildfire* is *hate*. What has *hate* to do with *wildfire*?

Comment: There are numerous words to describe fires in developed areas, namely [urban fires, town and city fires, building or structure fires, and transportation fires, depending on how specific you want to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fires). The meta question, in my opinion, should warrant its own question, because I can't seem to find anything that'd explain **pain** being used.

Comment: @vth, The whole point of the question is to be **not** specific, as you will notice.

Comment: Then please provide an example. It'd go a long way in helping us understand what you're truly asking for. As for the meta question, I have yet to find any authoritative source that provides **pain** as an antonym for **wildfire**. Merriam-Webster? [Nope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/wildfire). Oxford? [Nope](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=thesaurus&query=wildfire). Collins? [Nope](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/english-thesaurus?q=wildfire).

Comment: What is the word for the human condition which presupposes that every expression must have an equal and opposite, and that there is total symmetry in language? I think an "urban fire" is the best you are going to get.

Comment: @VTH 'Pain' the antonym cited in the question, and verified as a search result [here]( https://www.powerthesaurus.org/wildfire/antonyms) is 'hate'. I'm wondering if it was some odd typo, maybe for 'heat' (not that that makes much more sense) that got picked up and re-cited by content recyclers

Comment: There are lots of fires that don't take place in what we might call 'developed zones' eg that are carried out for land management purposes, such as stubble burning and muir-burn. These are controlled burns in countryside areas, but can turn into wild fires if the wind changes or they are badly managed. IS that the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: @Spagirl Yes 'hate' is a very strange idea for an antonym of 'wildfire'. It implies that one definition of 'wildfire' is 'love' or 'like'. I wonder whether someone has found 'wildfire' being used as a metaphor for sexual passion, added 2 and 2 and got 395.

Comment: @BoldBen I see now that https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/wildfire?s=t cite Roget's 21st Century Thesaurus, Third Edition  as the source, so my typo theory seems unlikely. I don't have a Roget's to hand...

Comment: Is a fire in a fireplace "wild"?  How about the fire in your gas furnace?

Comment: Not entirely OT: it is possible to _tame fire_. A fairly unique event, though... and I don't imagine that most fires that were tamed were, in fact, wildfires to start with. Courtesy of [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=taming+fire&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz0s7GqpfdAhXRSsAKHUjrAj4QpwUIIQ&biw=1024&bih=646&dpr=2): _"Homo erectus may also have tamed fire, perhaps as early as 1.6 million years ago."_
@WS2 A rhetorical question, I know, but "morphological Manicheism"?

Comment: @Spagirl Following your link I think the reference only relates to the synonyms, I'm not convinced that Roget's have 'hate' as an antonym. My very old and basic Roget's doesn't even give antonyms at all so far as I can see.

Comment: @VTH Where in the world is ***pain*** coming from! The question is plain and simple. Do let me know if you have any misgivings.

Comment: @VTH See also the answer by  Richard Erickson below, to get the drift.

Comment: @Kris The word **pain** was a simple mistake, a mistake which I unfortunately could not detect and fix in time, plain and simple. Apologies for any misunderstandings.

Comment: @VTH And hordes have up voted the "mistake."

Comment: @Kris The point I was trying to get across still remains: no authoritative sources have confirmed of the existence of any antonyms to the word **wildfire**.

Comment: @VTH What is Google for?!

Answer (score 7):

From a firefighting perspective, there are two broad types of unwanted fires. 
Structural fires and wildfires. 
As a rough rule of thumb, structural fires occurring when a building is burning. 
These tend to be more urban and occur in areas where people inhabit. 
Conversely, wildfires refer to fires that occur in rural areas that have fewer people and are sometimes called wildlands (hence wildfire). 
The [Wikipedia article on wildfires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildfire) provides a nice overview.
Forest fires are a type of wildfire that many people use as a synonym.
The reason firefighting splits the two types of fires is that they require different gear types to fight and use different methods. 
Also, many (probably most) firefighters are only trained to fight structural or wildland fires but not both.

Wildfires are also closely related to [controlled burns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_burn), which can be done as a land management tool.
A controlled burn that gets out of hand can become a wildfires.
Conversely, controlled burn can be used as a tool to fight wildfires.
Also, wildfires are sometimes left to burn in either remote wilderness areas or managed areas that where scheduled to be burned.

Personally, I received wildland firefighting training in college to help out with controlled burns, which gave me my perspective to answer this question.
We were taught explicitly that we were not qualified to fight structural training. 
 The US Forest Service has a [career webpage](https://www.fs.fed.us/managing-land/fire/careers) for people interested in more details about this training.

Also, sorry but I cannot help you with your *meta*-question.

Answer (score 0):

Love/hate
Fire/ice
Cold hearted-hate
You set my heart on fire-love 
That line of thinking is likely the derivation for the meta.

To answer the question:

controlled fire

Comment: Hi Grammaticallychallenged! Welcome to English Language & Usage. We like to see answers with solid explanations and authoritative references. Perhaps you could edit your answer to provide more detail and some links to support it? Also, you might want to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through [the help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Actually, your second answer is wrong. The opposite of wildfire would be a structural fire.

Answer (score 0):

Fire in a developed area, controlled, life-sustaining and nurturing, is 'home fire':

> **home fire**, *n.*
>   ....
>   A fire burning in the hearth of a home. Frequently *fig.* and in figurative contexts, with allusion to the home or to family life in general.
>
> [*OED*](http://oed.com/)

A 'bale-fire' (noun, types of bonfire, signal fire, beacon fire) might answer, but such fires could as easily be in undeveloped as developed areas.

As to the meta question regarding how 'hate' is an antonym, [Grammaticallychallenged's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/314504/grammaticallychallenged) is on target:

> wildfire = ardor = love, thus opposite hate.